# Javascript object coming through empty on server side

Tags: javascript, express

I have a client-side script running to send the string "Y" to the server. I set up a console.log on the client-side (which you can see below) and another on the server-side. The one on the client-side works, but the one logs an "empty" object.. it just shows "{}".
How do I get my data to stay in the object?

```
                const status = "Y";

                const options = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: status
                fetch('/events/<%- event.id %>/prompt', options)

                console.log(options.body)
```

Here's my route for context:

```
router.route('events/:id/prompt')
    .get(catchAsync(events.showPrompt))
    .post(catchAsync(events.checkIn))
```

And my controller:

```
module.exports.checkIn = async(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
}
```

How do I get the object to come through to the server?

Comment: Have you tried using an actual *object* instead of just a string?

Comment: you should parse the JSON string to a JSON object

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus all I want is the string, though. And options is an object. How do I get the string through in the object?

Comment: @about14sheep all I want is the string so I don't want to parse it to an object just to parse it back to a string (unless that's the difference between me sending it to the server).

Comment: If `req.body` is empty on the server, then that's because you don't have the appropriate Express middleware for the incoming content-type.  The body is not read automatically by Express, so you must have the appropriate middleware for the incoming content-type.  For example: `app.use(express.json())` will install the middleware for reading incoming JSON if that's your content type.

Comment: And, your incoming content and `content-type` sent with the request must be correct also to line up with the middleware.  In your code example, it appears you're just sending text so perhaps you would use `app.use(express.text())` and make sure that the `content-type` is set to `text/plain`.

Comment: @jfriend00 you my friend are a genius -- changing the content type to 'text/plain' and declaring app.use(express.text()) in my app.js fixed the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending `"y"` as the content and receiving that in Express, you need two things:

1. You need to make sure the `content-type` is set to `text/plain` on the request.
2. You need the appropriate middleware that will read that `text/plain` body.

   app.use(express.text())

Then, you will find the body in `req.body` within any express request handler registered after the above middleware.

---

You could pick different content-types also such as `application/json`, the corresponding middleware for that `content-type` app.use(express.json())` and then format the body data in that format.

---

It's important to realize that Express does not by itself read the body of an incoming request.  It reads the headers, but not the body by default.  If you want the body to be read, then you need middleware that is looking for whatever `content-type` the incoming request has, reads the body, parses it from whatever it's format is and puts the resulting parsed data into `req.body`. Express comes with a number of built-in middleware for popular content-types.

Answer (score 0):

Status is a string. However body have to take a object with key-value pair. If send like with like below, then you get object which contains status on the backend side.

```
body: {status: status}
```

Comment: Still coming through as "{}" although this seemed like the most promising solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

Problem from :

- Client : you choose *Content-type': 'application/json'* , so your body must be json format , something like  *body : { status }* . Make sure you sent exact object with browser debug , because some call api package can change value of request.
- Server : Some nodejs framework need parse the value is sent from client before read it (Exp : app.use(express.json()) with Express)